# What is this: () => {}

Tags: javascript, meteor

I don't achieve to get any information about `() => {}`

An example in Meteor:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
});
```

What is its function?

Thank you so much.

Comment: arrow syntax as per es6 standards. That's where you `this` is available and need not to mention and basically you have to say a new syntax for callback anonymous functions.

Comment: This is a shorthand for anonymous function in es6. Also called as Arrow function.
You can get more information over here.Arrow functions capture the this value of the enclosing context.

    https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That is ES6 short hand for an anonymous function definition in javascript.

Short hand for:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

});
```

Specifically in this case, it's a callback that is invoked once the startup method for Meteor is run.

The benefit with using `=>` is that `this` is bound at the appropriate scope.

Comment: More like shorthand for `function() {}.bind(this)`..

Comment: What is wrong with this answer guys?

Comment: @Jai as was explained, the two functions are not equivalent, because `this` has a different meaning within them. Which is actually a huge difference.

Comment: @MatisLepik Where do you see `this` in the question? and yes Alan needed to mention that okay!!!

Comment: It's only a "huge" difference if you need proper binding of `this.`

Comment: @Jai The question was about the arrow syntax, which `this` obviously pertains to. It wasn't in the question because OP doesn't know what an arrow function is, obviously he's not going to know to ask specifically about `this`. Nevertheless it is an important part of the answer, and this person's answer implied that the two are functionally identical, which is incorrect.

Comment: @MatisLepik correct! agreed.....!!!